# Read dot matrix printer data through parallel port

Tags: parallel-port, dot-matrix-printer

Current setup:

I have a PLC that, under certain conditions, will print information to a dot-matrix printer that it is connected to.

Desired setup:

Replace the printer with a PC (which has a parallel port) that can read the data and save it to a file.

Does anybody know of any software that can accomplish this? The platform would be Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link to a device](http://pcl.to/capture/hardware.html) (and software) to do that. I don't have any experience with it.